# Reading line with spaces in C Programming and segmentating the words

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have inputs similar to the following ones:

Johnhy ID5 409-208

I need to be able to read the input and to organize the output on a structure like:

Name: Johnhy
Type: ID5
ID Number: 409-208

But I'm struggling to find literature about how to handle the segment using the spaces. I'm pretty new to C, I confess.

Comment: Read lines, detect spaces.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment you want us to do for you, no?

Comment: @GabrielStaples I wish that I had that age. I'm trying to learn this for personnel reasons.

Comment: In that case, if you can update your question with some compilable code showing you acquiring the inputs, and in what code form, I'll see if I can return to this question and provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this next bit if you want to see how to handle individual characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char mstring[] = "Hello World";
    char space = ' ';
    int a = 0;
    
    while ( a < strlen(mstring))
    {
        if (mstring[a] == space)
        {
            printf ("found space!");
        }
        a++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since my other answer wasn't acceptable, here is how to do it. But I think you'd learn a lot if you tried to write a function which returns each word based on the spaces. It depends on what you're trying to learn.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char mstring[] = "Johnhy ID5 409-208";
    char name[50];
    char type[50];
    char id[50] ;

    
    sscanf(mstring, "%s %s %s", name, type, id);
    printf("Name:%s\nType:%s\nID:%s\n", name, type, id);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does not produce what OP wants. Also, use a `for` loop.

Comment: He wants to know how to handle spaces.  I am just giving a clue. It's my program and if I prefer while loops then I will use one.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped, and it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables with appropriate lengths and:

```
scanf("%s %s %s", name, type, id);
```